# Splitting strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I tried to split data as below, but the error "dat.split is not a function" displays. Anyone know how can I solve this problem?

```
var dat = new Date("2009/12/12");
var r = dat.split('/');
```

Comment: @Jin Yong: Was there a special reason that made you delete your post? It's a valid question after all... (@Jeff Atwood: Thanks for undeleting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `split()` a Date - you can `split()` a String, though:

```
var dat = "2009/12/12"; 
var r = dat.split('/');
```

returns:

```
["2009", "12", "12"]
```

To do the equivalent with a date, use something like this:

```
var dat = new Date();
var r = [dat.getFullYear(), dat.getMonth() + 1, dat.getDate()];
```

returns:

```
[2009, 4, 17]
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dat.toString().split('/');
```

but this solution is locale dependent

Comment: `new Date("2009/12/12").toString().split('/'); // ["Sat Dec 12 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"]`

Comment: hey did I just found a bug in stackoverflow, I am pretty sure I deleted my answer because I found there's a problem as noted by the comment above. Plus, the author of the comment above is 'null'.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to get the year, month and day? In that case you'd be better off using a non-locale dependent solution and calling the following functions:

```
dat.getDay();
dat.getMonth();
dat.getFullYear();
```

Sure they won't be zero padded, but that's easy enough to do.